# MessageDefinitionSends Rest API successful with response "Queued" for request type "SYNC"

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am firing a SYNC message

```
{
  "To" : [ {
    "Address" : "test@test.com",
    "SubscriberKey" : "test_key",
    "ContactAttributes" : {
      "SubscriberAttributes" : {
        "last_name" : "Kiran",
        "first_name" : "Kumar",
      }
    }
  } ],
  "Options" : {
    "RequestType" : "SYNC"
  }
}
```

And receiving following response

```
{
  "requestId" : "test_req_id",
  "responses" : [ {
    "recipientSendId" : "send_id",
    "hasErrors" : false,
    "messages" : [ "Queued" ]
  } ]
}
```

I am assuming this request is "Queued" (based on response), even though i set request type as "SYNC".

My requirement is to send messages synchronously.

Couple of questions

1. How can we confirm the request is marked as synchronous.
2. Is there any issues in above request payload in order to send SYNC messages.

Comment: it appears your request is wrong based on the help doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm. you are using [] where the help doc has {}

Comment: @EazyE thanks for reply. i tried sending one {} not []. Still no luck.

Comment: Both SYNC and ASYNC will queue. You can [retrieve the message's status](https://www.postman.com/salesforce-developers/workspace/salesforce-developers/folder/14448118-c3dd2202-a771-4b3c-b2a2-68b8d99dc364?ctx=documentation) and see what's going on with it.

Answer (score 0):

SO I tested this out,

The response you have listed in the valid, sending message response.

If there was an error you would get more detail such as

```
{
    "To": {
        "Address": "hello@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "123567",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "First_Name": "Hello"
            }
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "RequestType": "SYNC"
    }
}
```

Provides this response due to the emailaddress

```
{
    "requestId": "4a39d1b6-2a1a-4210-ac3a-0ade1209d790",
    "responses": [
        {
            "recipientSendId": "4a39d1b6-2a1a-4210-ac3a-0ade1209d790",
            "hasErrors": true,
            "messageErrors": [
                {
                    "messageErrorCode": 180008,
                    "messageErrorStatus": "Unable to queue Triggered Send request.  There are no valid subscribers."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```